# "aid in" with the noun

Tags: differences, prepositions, collocation

I often find it confusing when to use "aid in" instead of "aid."

[A similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293756/difference-between-aid-and-aid-in) has been posted before, but this thread mainly addresses when a gerund, or participle is the object of the preposition "in."

Could anyone explain why "aid in" is used in the following examples? What would be the difference if it said "aid" instead?

- Interpol is sending a response team to the French city of Nice to help identify victims and **aid in** the investigation into the truck attack that left at least 84 people dead.(http://www.nytimes.com/aponline/2016/07/15/world/europe/ap-eu-france-truck-attack-the-latest.html?_r=0)
- While cutting down on the most egregious polluters in any area comes with multiple local benefits — cleaner air, more efficient and cost-effective electricity production — the authors’ particular focus in conducting the study was helping to **aid in** global climate efforts.(https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/energy-environment/wp/2016/07/07/this-could-be-a-completely-different-strategy-for-tackling-the-worlds-carbon-emissions/)

Comment: I'd say that the different variants are largely synonymous. 'Aid' is a verb that can often take a direct object or an in-phrase. The 'in' has a pragmatic contribution, emphasising the 'additional contribution to existing efforts' aspect and thus connoting cameraderie, but could be argued to be semantically redundant. Omitting it depersonalises the overall effect; I like it here.

Comment: I agree with Edwin. The "in" *could* be omitted in both sentences, but it reads better *with* the word "in". In the first sentence, for example, it could be read as meaning "aid [the existing investigators with] the investigation ..."

Answer (score 1):

In both of the examples presented, *"in"* is an adverbial portion of a phrasal verb, a particle used in this instance to impart the case of the statement.

*"To Aid in [something]"* is in the dative case, while *"To Aid [something]"* is in the accusative.

Since cases in English are now vestigial, there is little difference in modern usage between the two.

Comment: I can just barely make out how aiding someone in doing something used to be a dative since they were the beneficiary. But how does using the word dative make sense today now that we've lost case inflections for it?

Comment: As I said, cases are vestigial (The only actual inflection I can think of off the top of my head is "to whom"). Usage of case-based statements is similarly vestigial. It's there, but it's not mandatory.